# What is the best way to identify a device by Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, identity

I want something to identify devices.
Condition :
- I can get this identification from my device
- Devices how discovered me by Bluetooth can get it

I try bluetooth mac address but I think access to mac adress now is just for system apps ,this is [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067259/bluetoothadapter-getaddress-return-020000000000).
 
I try Bluetooth UUIDs but the problem is that I can get UUIDs automatically by discovering.
And of course Bluetooth name is not a choise because we can found 2 devices with the same name

Comment: Once you "identify" devices, what is the usefulness of the information? Are you pairing? If not, why?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- to detect if a user of the application is near to the other user